# Javascript in Angular. Value, match and replace throw a exception.. Why?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this little javascript I want to use in a Angular service or controller.

```
  function cprCheck(frm) {
        var cpr = frm.cpr.value
        if (cpr.match(/[0-9]{6}\-[0-9]{4}/)) {
            cpr = cpr.replace(/\-/g, "");
            var chk = 0;
            for (i = 9; i > -1; i--) {
                chk += (+cpr.charAt(i)) * ((i > 2) ? (10 - i) : (4 - i));
            }
            if (chk % 11 == 0) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Value, match and replace throw a exception.. Why?

Comment: *"Value, match and replace throw a exception.. Why?"*. It explains why, doesn't it?

Comment: have you tried making the match a string? '/[0-9]{6}\-[0-9]{4}/'

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: You're trying to change the field value directly. This is not the best way to do it. You'd better assign a model to this form and then change the model value or at least use the $setViewValue function. Refer to this link: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

Comment: Exception: TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Comment: Sari:  Yes, and I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with a different method:

```
        var validateCprConfig = {
        checkModulus: true,
        cprRegex: /^\d{10}$/,
        cleanupRegex: /-/g,
        daysInMonth: [31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31],
        controlNumbers: [4, 3, 2, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1] // via http://da.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPR-nummer#Kontrol_af_personnummer
    };

    var isModulus11 = function (val) {
        var components = (val + '').split('');
        var control = validateCprConfig.controlNumbers;
        var sum = 0;

        angular.forEach(components, function (current, index) {
            var currentControl = control[index];
            sum += current * currentControl;
        });

        return sum % 11 === 0;
    };
```